# Javascript related selects populated with xml not working in Chrome or IE(without compatibility view)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, google-chrome

I have a webpage at work that was written many years ago that is giving me issues as we try and update it for use in more modern browsers.

The error I am getting in Chrome is "Uncaught TypeError: xml_map.namedRecordset is not a function"

This is causing the select boxes that we have to not populate as it appears to have an issue with the xml parsing.

The javascript for the select boxes is here:

```
<script language="JScript">

$(function() {
    var currentDate = new Date();
    $('#datepicker1').datepicker({
        inline: true,
        showOtherMonths: true,
        dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
    });
    $("#datepicker1").datepicker("setDate", "-30d");
});

$(function() {
    var currentDate = new Date();
    $('#datepicker2').datepicker({
        inline: true,
        showOtherMonths: true,
        dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
    });
    $("#datepicker2").datepicker("setDate", currentDate);
});

//date_index_choice allows us to use Report_Date date index if it exists, otherwise we use Cypress date (Document Creation Time)
var date_index_choice = "[Document Creation Time]";

// Fill first drop down list when desired
function refill()
    {
    FillSortDropDownWithFields(queryform.dropdown1, xml_map.namedRecordset("", "category_list.category"));
    }

// Refill second drop down list when desired
function refill2(x)
    {
    dRecordSet=xml_map.namedRecordset("", "category_list.category");
    dRecordSet.MoveFirst();
    x = x - 1
    for (i=0; i<x; i++)
        {
        dRecordSet.MoveNext();
        }
    //"category_list.category.sub_category"
    FillSortDropDownWithFields2(queryform.dropdown2, xml_map.namedRecordset("", "category_list.category.sub_category"));
    }

//Refill dropdown menu
function refill3(x)
    {
    dRecordSet=xml_map.namedRecordset("", "category_list.category.sub_category");
    dRecordSet.MoveFirst();
    x = x - 1;
    for (i=0; i<x; i++)
        {
        dRecordSet.MoveNext();
        }
    //"category_list.category.sub_category"
    FillSortDropDownWithFields3(queryform.dropdown3, xml_map.namedRecordset("", "category_list.category.sub_category.report_name"));
    }

// Fill dropdown with field names from the ADO RecordSet
function FillSortDropDownWithFields(oDropDown, oRecordSet)
    {
    // Clear out the current drop down values
    //alert(oRecordSet.RecordCount);
    var record_length       = 0;

    for (i=0; i < oDropDown.options.length;i+1)
        {
        oDropDown.options[i]=null;
        }

    record_length       = oRecordSet.RecordCount + 1
    //Get to the first element of the dataset
    oRecordSet.MoveFirst();
    // add each of the elements in the dataset to the drop-down
    for (i=0; i < record_length; i++)
        {
        oField = oRecordSet.fields;
        //alert(oField(2).value);
        if(i == 0)
            oDropDown.options[i]=new Option("--Select--","--Slelct--")
        else
            oDropDown.options[i]=new Option(oField(1).value,oField(1).value)
        if(i > 0)
            oRecordSet.MoveNext(); 
        }
    }

function FillSortDropDownWithFields2(oDropDown, oRecordSet)
    {   
    // Clear out the current drop down values
    for (i=1; i<oDropDown.options.length;i+1)
        {
        oDropDown.options[i]=null;
        }

    //alert(oRecordSet.RecordCount);
    //Get to the first element of the dataset
    oRecordSet.MoveFirst();

    // add each of the elements in the dataset to the drop-down
    for (i = 1; i <= oRecordSet.RecordCount; i++)
        {
        oField = oRecordSet.fields;
        //alert(oField(4).value);
        oDropDown.options[i]=new Option(oField(1).value,oField(1).value)
        oRecordSet.MoveNext(); 
        }
    }

//Fills the thirs drop down menu  
function FillSortDropDownWithFields3(oDropDown, oRecordSet)
    {   
    // Clear out the current drop down values
    for (i=1; i < oDropDown.options.length;i+1)
        {
        oDropDown.options[i]=null;
        }

    //alert(oRecordSet.RecordCount);
    //Get to the first element of the dataset
    oRecordSet.MoveFirst();

    // add each of the elements in the dataset to the drop-down
    for (i = 1; i <= oRecordSet.RecordCount; i++)
        {
        oField = oRecordSet.fields;
        //alert(oField(0).value);
        oDropDown.options[i]=new Option(oField(0).value,oField(0).value)
        oRecordSet.MoveNext(); 
        }
    }

//Gets indexes from CYpress generated XML file
function load_indexes()
    {
    var report_name             = "";
    var rdm_group_size          = 0;
    var rdm_report_size         = 0;
    var rdm_inx_size            = 0;
    //var xmlDoc                    = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    var array_counter           = 0;
    var invalid_index_counter   = 0;
    var group_counter           = 0;
    var report_counter          = 0;
    var sub_report_counter      = 0;
    var index_list_counter      = 0;
    var index_counter           = 0;
    var index_name_array_counter= 0;
    var total_index_count       = 0;
    var index_name_array        = new Array();

    //xmlDoc.async="false";
    //xmlDoc.onreadystatechange=verify;

    //alert("Before XML Load");
    //xmlDoc.load("GR_Prd_DV1_rdm_groups.xml");
    xmlObj=xmlDoc.documentElement;
    /*
    if (xmlDoc.readyState != 4)
        {
        alert("XML file did not load");
        return;
        }   
    */
    //alert("After XML Load");

    //RDM Groups List
    //alert("Initial Tag:" + xmlObj.tagName);
    //alert("Report_list:" + xmlObj.childNodes(0).tagName);
    //alert("Group Length:" + xmlObj.childNodes(0).childNodes.length);
    //alert("Report Parameter:" + document.queryform.dropdown3.value);
    while (report_counter < xmlObj.childNodes(0).childNodes.length)
        {
        //alert("Report Names:" + xmlObj.childNodes(0).childNodes(report_counter).getAttribute("obj_name"));
        //Loop through RDM Groups
        //alert("Report Counter=" + report_counter);
        if(xmlObj.childNodes(0).childNodes(report_counter).getAttribute("obj_name") == document.queryform.dropdown3.value)
            {
            //alert("Reports:" + xmlObj.childNodes(0).childNodes(report_counter).tagName)
            //Sub Report Loop
            index_list_counter = 0;
            while(index_list_counter < xmlObj.childNodes(0).childNodes(report_counter).childNodes.length)
                {
                 if(xmlObj.childNodes(0).childNodes(report_counter).childNodes(index_list_counter).tagName == "index_list")
                    {
                    //alert("index_list:" + xmlObj.childNodes(0).childNodes(report_counter).childNodes(index_list_counter).tagName);    
                    //Loop through indexes
                    //index_counter = 0;
                    while(index_counter < xmlObj.childNodes(0).childNodes(report_counter).childNodes(index_list_counter).childNodes.length)
                        {
                        index_name_array[index_counter] = xmlObj.childNodes(0).childNodes(report_counter).childNodes(index_list_counter).childNodes(index_counter).getAttribute("obj_name");
                        total_index_count   = index_counter;
                        //alert("index name:" + xmlObj.childNodes(0).childNodes(report_counter).childNodes(index_list_counter).childNodes(index_counter).getAttribute("obj_name"));
                        index_counter = index_counter + 1;
                        }//end of looping through indexes
                    }//end of index_list (if)
                index_list_counter = index_list_counter + 1;
                }//End of index_list    
            }//End of Report Name Compare(if)
        report_counter = report_counter + 1;
        }//End of Looping though Groups

    //Clear out current index drop down values
        for (i=1;i<queryform.dropdown4.options.length;i+1)
            {
            //alert ("Clearing index:"+queryform.dropdown4.options[i])
            queryform.dropdown4.options[i] = null;
            }

    //Set date_index_choice to use Cypress date by default
    date_index_choice = "[Document Creation Time]";
    //alert("total_index_count(" + total_index_count + ")")
    while(array_counter <= total_index_count)
        {
        //alert("Adding Index:" + index_name_array[array_counter])
        //Add to indices to index list unless it is the generic date index, report ID or name, or old category index
        if (index_name_array[array_counter] != "Report_Date" && index_name_array[array_counter] != "Report ID" && index_name_array[array_counter] != "Report Category")
            queryform.dropdown4.options[array_counter + 1 - invalid_index_counter]=new Option(index_name_array[array_counter],index_name_array[array_counter])
            else 
                {
                //Use Report_Date for date search index if it exists
                if (index_name_array[array_counter] == "Report_Date")
                    date_index_choice = "[Report_Date]";
                invalid_index_counter = invalid_index_counter + 1;
                }
        array_counter = array_counter + 1;
        }
    //alert("end of Load Index Function");
    }


function reorder_date(string)
    {   
    year = string.substring(string.length-4);
    month = string.substring(0,string.indexOf("/"));
    day = string.substring(string.indexOf("/")+1,string.lastIndexOf("/"));
    next_string= year + "," + month + "," + day;
//  alert(next_string);
    return next_string;
    }
/*@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@                                                                            @@
@@ Function:     submit_query                                                 @@
@@ Returns:      n/a                                                          @@
@@ Description:  prepares the form objects for query then submits query       @@
@@                                                                            @@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@*/
function submit_query()
  {
 var querystring   =""; 


//Check that a report name is selected
 if (queryform.dropdown3.value == "")
    {
        alert("Please select a Category, Subcategory, and/or Report Name");
        return;
    } 

//Check for criteria value entered but index not selected
 if(queryform.dropdown4.value == "" && queryform.query_text.value !="") 
    {
    alert("Please select which Criteria to use or clear the Criteria text");
    return;
    }

//Check for criteria index select but no value entered
 if(queryform.dropdown4.value != "" && queryform.query_text.value =="") 
    {
    alert("Please enter Criteria text or clear Criteria selection");
    return;
    }

//Check for from date not entered but to date entered
 if(queryform.date1.value == "" && queryform.date2.value != "") 
    {
    alert("You must enter a beginning date");
    return;
    }

if(queryform.dropdown3.value == "All Reports" && queryform.dropdown4.value == "")
    {
    alert("This search requires Criteria to be entered");
    return;
    }

 if(queryform.dropdown3.value != "All Reports")
    querystring  = "[Document Distribution Report]=\"" + queryform.dropdown3.value + "\"";


 if(queryform.dropdown4.value != "")
    {
    if(queryform.dropdown3.value != "All Reports")
        querystring = querystring + " and ";

//logic for using numeric indices
    if(queryform.dropdown4.value != "AP Acct Nbr" && queryform.dropdown4.value != "Branch Nbr" && queryform.dropdown4.value != "Company Nbr" && queryform.dropdown4.value != "Employee Nbr" && queryform.dropdown4.value != "Tractor Nbr")
        querystring = querystring + "[" + queryform.dropdown4.value + "]=\"" +  queryform.query_text.value + "\""
        else querystring = querystring + "[" + queryform.dropdown4.value + "]=" +  queryform.query_text.value;
    }

 if(queryform.date1.value != "" && queryform.date2.value == "")
   querystring = querystring + " and "+date_index_choice+"=tstamp(" + reorder_date(queryform.date1.value) + ")";

 if(queryform.date1.value != "" && queryform.date2.value != "")
   querystring = querystring + " and "+date_index_choice+">=tstamp(" + reorder_date(queryform.date1.value) + ") and "+date_index_choice+"<=tstamp(" + reorder_date(queryform.date2.value) + ",23,59)";


//Check for null query string
 if(querystring == "") 
    {
    alert("This search requires Criteria and/or Date Range");
    return;
    }


  //alert(querystring); 
  //parent.document.frames(1).document.CypressQuery.DoQuery(querystring);
    top.open("http://mastodon.grhq.gfs.com:8080/DocumentViewer/Query.html?InitQuery="+querystring+"%20");
  }

function queryform_onsubmit()
  {
  submit_query();
  return(false);  
  }
</script>
```

The html is here:

```
<body onLoad="refill();" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="center">
<!-- Include the XML files with the report list for the drop down  -->
<XML src="MapFile.xml" ID="xml_map"></XML>
<XML src="GFS_RDM_rpt_inx.xml" ID="xmlDoc"></XML>

<form LANGUAGE="JScript" ONSUBMIT="return queryform_onsubmit()" name="queryform">
<div id="header">
        <p>Cypress Web Query</p>
</div>
<div id="main">
<div id="container1">
<div id="categories">
    <p>*Category:&nbsp;
    <select onchange="refill2(this.options.selectedIndex)" name="dropdown1">
        <option selected>--Select--</option>
    </select>
    </p>
    <p>*Subcategory:&nbsp;
    <select onchange="refill3(this.options.selectedIndex)" name="dropdown2">
        <option selected>--Select--</option>
    </select>
    </p>
    <p>*Report Name:&nbsp;
    <select onchange="load_indexes()" name="dropdown3">
        <option selected>--Select--</option>
    </select>
    </p>
    <p style="color:#505050">Criteria:&nbsp;
    <select id="dropdown4" name="dropdown4">
        <option selected>--Select--</option>
    </select>
    <input class="formFIELD" size="20" id="query_text" name="query_text" type="text">
    </p>
    <p style="font-size: medium">*Required fields in RED</p>
</div>
</div>

<div id="container2">
<div id="reportdates">
    <p>Report Dates between
        <input class="formFIELD" value="" size="10" id="datepicker1" name="date1" type="text">
    </p>
    <p>and
        <input class="formFIELD" value="" size="10" id="datepicker2" name="date2" type="text">
    </p>
        <input value="Submit" name="Submit" type="submit">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input value="Reset" id="Reset5" type="reset" name="Reset">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
</body>
```

The xml file is very large so here is a section for an idea of the structure:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <Map_File file_use= "Mapping file for page indexes">
                    <category_list>
                                    <category obj_name= "Accounts Payable">
                                                   <sub_category obj_name="1099 Reports">
                                                                    <report_name obj_name= "AP145"/>
                                                                    <report_name obj_name= "AP245"/>
                                                   </sub_category>
                                                   <sub_category obj_name="A/P Close Reports">
                                                                    <report_name obj_name= "AP136 1 Invc Accrual"/>
                                                                    <report_name obj_name= "AP136 28 Invc Accrual"/>
                                                                    <report_name obj_name= "AP136 61 Invc Accrual"/>
                                                                    <report_name obj_name= "AP136 999 Invc Accrual"/>
                                                                    <report_name obj_name= "AP175 28 Invc Dist Close"/>
                                                                    <report_name obj_name= "AP1751 Invc Dist Close"/>
                                                                    <report_name obj_name= "AP1751 Out of Balance"/>
                                                                    <report_name obj_name= "AP1751 Invc Accr Entries"/>
                                                                    <report_name obj_name= "AP17561"/>
                                                                    <report_name obj_name= "AP175999 Invc Dist Close"/>
                                                                    <report_name obj_name= "AP175999 Out of Balance"/>
                                                                    <report_name obj_name= "AP175999 Invc Accr Entries"/>
                                                                    <report_name obj_name= "AP230"/>
                                                                    <report_name obj_name= "AP23028"/>
                                                                    <report_name obj_name= "AP230TH1 Open Payables Rpt"/>
                                                                    <report_name obj_name= "AP230999 Open Payables Rpt"/>
                                                                    <report_name obj_name= "GP162 Cash Disc Alloc"/>
                                                                    <report_name obj_name= "GP16228 Cash Disc Alloc - CAN"/>
                                                                    <report_name obj_name= "GP16261 Cash Disc Alloc"/>
                                                                    <report_name obj_name= "GP162TH Cash Disc Alloc"/>
                                                   </sub_category>
                                </category>
                </category_list>
</Map_File>
```

I am admittedly not a web developer I am just trying to get this page working as it is an interface for one of our apps.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML Data Islands (XML-tag within HTML) were only supported by Internet Explorer. And even Microsoft removed support starting with IE 10: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh801224(v=vs.85).aspx

This is obviously some old code from long time ago. The reason you are getting this error in Chrome is because Chrome, and probably all modern browsers, doesn't recognize XML-tag and all functions associated with it.

I'm sorry, but you're going to have to rewrite this code to use modern, supported methods.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be the case.

I look forward to killing this page and creating anew from the ashes.  Unfortunately that will not be possible before our go live date of our application upgrade :/

Comment: I hear you. Problems like this make me question my career choices sometimes. ;) Whoever created this code was obviously only thinking of IE users.